# Are Swift generics separately compiled?

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to figure out how [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) generics work. Specifically, I didn't manage to find a precise statement about the compilation model. In C++, generics (templates) are not separately compiled as they are instantiated (at least in principle) for each call site. Java generics, instead, are separately compiled. What is the case with Swift, concerning separate compilation of generics?

Comment: I seem to recall this being talked about in one of the advanced WWDC session videos this year. Can't ben more specific though sorry :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a combination of the two, depending on what the optimizer decides will get better performance. They talk about it near the end of [WWDC Session 404: Advanced Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=404). The slide says:

> Swift can run generic code directly
>
> Optimizer can produce specialized versions of generic code at will
>
> - Separate compilation of generics
> - Faster compiles
> - Flexibility to trade code size for speed

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, it's similar to the C++ way. In a Swift generic function parameterized with `T`, you can directly access things with `T` like `T.self` at runtime. You can also do this in C++, but not in Java, where generics is only compile-time and type-erased afterwards.